# How to get know if a prop is called inside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Form` component, and an `Input` component. The form needs to be reusable, so everything's can be made only through the `Form`'s props. I want to give the ability to include a prop to the `Form`, which is an `focusOn` named object, which should contain an `id`, and an `event`. The id is the input element's id, which needs to be focused if the `event` is called. Simplified code:

```js
//...Form

render () {
  const { focusOn, inputs } = this.props;
  
  const focus = inputId => {
    const { id: targetId, event } = focusOn;
    if (inputId === targetId) { return event; }
    else { return null; }
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      inputs.map(({id, ...inputProps}) => (
        <Input focusOn={focus(id)} {...inputProps} />
      ))
    </div>
  )
}

//...Input

render () {
  const { focusOn, ...props } = this.props;
  
  if ("focusOn fires") {
    this.iRef.focus()
  }
  
  return <input ref={i = { this.iRef = i; }} {...props} />
}
```

The question is: what do I need to write instead of the `if ("focusOn fires") {/*...*/}` section?

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. Do you want to be able to focus on certain input from a parent component?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand some event fires outside of the `Form` and you would like to respond to it inside of a nested component.

I believe you have trouble with doing that in your code, because you need to change your mental approach. The `Input` doesn't care how/where/when the event fires. The `Input` only cares whether it should focus (or do whatever you want it to do) when new props come in.

Basically, you should keep these things separate. 
With this new approach, you can simply do something like this:

You can see it in action [in this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jqwn8ko7w).

```
//
// FORM COMPONENT
// You would pass down the "event" name down to the `Form` let's say as `parentEvent`
<Form
  parentEvent={event}
  inputs={[
    { id: "name", label: "name", event: "forName" },
  ]}
/>


//
// INSIDE OF FORM COMPONENT RENDER METHOD
return (
  <div>
    {inputs.map(({ event, ...inputProps }) => (
      //"shouldFocus" PROP THAT IS TRUE IF "parentEvent === input.event"
      <Input shouldFocus={parentEvent === event} {...inputProps} />
    ))}
  </div>
)

//
// INTPUT COMPONENT IMPLEMENTATION
class Input extends React.PureComponent {
  input = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    this.triggerFocus();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.triggerFocus();
  }

  // FOCUS THE INPUT -> TRIGGERED ON FIRST RENDER AND RERENDER IF SHOULD FOCUS
  triggerFocus = () => {
    if (this.props.shouldFocus) {
      this.input.current.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { id, label } = this.props;

    return (
      <input id={label} ref={this.input} {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}
```

In case I misunderstood what you are trying to do, let me know.